# PHP search in one table only

Tags: php

I have one member table in mysql database, all i need is search a member in that table by first name. Is there a quick and dirty solution in this ? Thanks

Comment: sorry, we aren't supernaturals who can guess your database structure and code.

Comment: You should probably mention what database you're using, at the very least. (And tag your question with it, while you're at it, then people who can answer your question are more likely to find it. :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstName  ='".mysql_real_escape_string($firstName)."'");
```

edited the solution from Serty was of course the best

Comment: Should not it be `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstName = ='".mysql_real_escape_string($firstName)."'");`

Comment: You probably want to remove one of the =s, you have two in there now.

Comment: what will be the mysqli version of that query ? do i not need to use LIKE ?